# Filter HTML Json based grid by Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new at Json,
I have rendered html templete grid using jason data,
but I have to bind drop downs using json and filter the grid based on these dropdown values.
Now I am confuse how can I generate joson again for each dropdown and after that for filtering,
I am using asp.net C# code at back end please give me easy and right path.

Comment: from where do you get the jSON

Comment: I have to get data from my c# class method

Answer (score 0):

save this json in the hidden textBox. And Every Time at the Dropdown change event take it from that textBox. As is is hidden, it won't be visible also.

Hope, it helps you :)